# How to represent nested data structures using Perl 6 classes?

Tags: raku

Last time I had to deal with such data, I used something like array-of-hashes, where each hash could have hash values etc. While looping through different indices/keys, it was very difficult not to get lost, so I presume there should be a better solution. Since I have no experience in OOP, I don't know, how to start...

Suppose in our city, we have a `Library` (whose contents has been digitized into txt-files) with several rooms: `1_red_room`, `2_blue_room`, and `3_white_room`. In every room, there are many books, every `book` having: `author's_name`, `title`, and `text` (read from txt files) divided into `pages`(with numbers).

Given a `$word`, for every room, the program should list:

```
room_name, with the overall number of `$word` contexts in all its books
  list of authors, who use this word, with number of contexts
    for every author, list of books, with number of contexts
      for every book, list of pages, with number of contexts
```

Example of the output:

```
Word: cucumber
TOTAL: 654
1_red_room: 234
  author: John Smith: 70
    title: "In the wild": 3
      page_50:  1
      page_150: 2
    title: "Hello world": 10
      page_1: 2
      page_5: 1
      page_7: 3
...
...
2_blue_room: 114
  author: Wendy Brown
    title: "In the dark": 43
      page_8: 7
...
```

So, is there a way to deal with such data with the help of user-defined classes (or probably using some other instruments)?

Comment: I hope to have a go at an answer a few hours from now unless there are already good ones by then. "While looping through different indices/keys, it was very difficult not to get lost". Perhaps there is a familiarity issue here. I think it would be helpful if you linked to an example of the sort of code you tried which you found tended to leave you lost.

Comment: @raiph Thanks. Finally I had my code work, and I use it frequently in my work. The actual names were different there (the structure consisted of: the names of textual corpora -> names of villages of their provenance -> names of speakers -> names of texts -> numbers of sentences). So, inside the loop for corpora, the main data was put into `my Hash @corpus`. To form data for every element of the @corpus, I used `my %text = number => $number, speaker => $speaker...` The code (some 250 lines) was difficult to write and modify, and now (several weeks after I made it work) difficult to read. :)

Comment: Hi Eugene... Idiomatic DRY version of `foo => $foo` is `:$foo`, so you could write `my %text = :$number, :$speaker...`. Are you willing / allowed to share your existing code? Do you find Håkon's code easier or harder to read than your existing code?

Comment: Thanks @raiph! I think Håkon's code is much clearer, but I'll be able to fully understand it when he explains the structure of his user-defined classes. I can't post my code online (it's a part of collective work), but I would gladly share it privately (not sure whether there are PMs on SO).

Comment: Eugene, use `gmail.com` @ user address `raiph dot mellor`. I hope to have time to digest and respond this week.

Comment: @raiph Thanks! I hope you've received it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would start at this. I would create a `Book` class. Then I would create a hash of books `%books` for each room:

```
my $total-count = 0;
my @room-info;
for @rooms -> $room {
    my @room-authors;
    my %room-authors;
    my $room-count = 0;
    for @(%books{$room}) -> $book {
        my $count = $book.contains-word( $word );
        if $count > 0 {
            $total-count += $count;
            $room-count += $count;
            my $author = $book.author;
            if %room-authors{$author}:exists {
                $(%room-authors{$author}).update($book, $word, $count);
            }
            else {
                %room-authors{$author} = Room-Author.new(
                    book => $book, word => $word, count => $count
                );
                @room-authors.push( $author );
            }
        }
    }
    if @room-authors.elems > 0 {
        @room-info.push(
            Room-Info.new(
                room => $room, room-count => $room-count,
                order => @room-authors, hash => %room-authors
            )
        );
    }
}
say "Word: $word";
say "TOTAL: $total-count";

for @room-info -> $room {
    my @room-authors = $room.order;
    my %room-authors = $room.hash;
    say $room.room ~ " : " ~ $room.room-count;
    for @room-authors -> $author-str {
        my $author = %room-authors{$author-str};
        say "  author: " ~ $author.name ~ " : " ~ $author.count;
        for @($author.titles) -> $title {
            say "    title: " ~ $title.title ~ " : " ~ $title.count;
            for @($title.pages) -> $page {
                say "      page_" ~ $page.page ~ ": " ~ $page.count;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here the classes `Page`, `Title`, `Room-Info`, `Book`, and `Room-Author` could look like (note: more details must be filled in in real code):

```
class Page {
    has Int $.page;
    has Int $.count;
}

class Title {
    has Str $.title;
    has Page @.pages;
    has Int $.count;
}

class Room-Info {
    has $.room;
    has $.room-count;
    has @.order;
    has %.hash;
}

class Book {
    has Str $.author;
    has Str $.title;
    has Str $.text;

    # checks how many times a word occurs in the book
    method contains-word ( $word, --> Int ) {
        return 2;  # Stub, insert more code here..
    }

    method get-page-matches( $word ) {
        return [Page.new(page => 50, count => 1),
                Page.new(page => 150, count => 2)]; # Stub, insert more code..
    }
}

class Room-Author {
    has Title @.titles;
    has Bool %!titles;
    has $.name;
    has $.count;

    submethod BUILD(:$book, :$word, :$!count) {
        my $title = $book.title;
        $!name = $book.author;
        %!titles{$title} = True;
        @!titles.push(
            Title.new(title => $title,
                      pages => $book.get-page-matches( $word ),
                      count => $!count,
                     )
        );
    }
    method update( $book, $word, $count ) {
        my $title = $book.title;
        $!count += $count;
        my $author = $book.author; # should be the same as $.name.. 
        if %!titles{$title}:exists {
            die "Unexpected: Duplicate title '$title' for $author";
        }
        else {
            %!titles{$title} = True;
            my Page @pages = $book.get-page-matches( $word );
            @!titles.push(
                Title.new(title => $title,
                          pages => $book.get-page-matches( $word ),
                          count => $count,
                         ) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems very elegant! So could you please say a few words about what classes/methods you would use? I see `Book`, `Room-Info`, and `Room-Author` class. How are they organized?

Comment: @EugeneBarsky Sure! I will be away from the computer for a while now, so I will come back to this later..

Comment: Thanks!! There's no hurry. I have a working program now, but I want to make a more general one in future.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanations!! I'll explore the code and maybe ask some new questions.